# Does each positive integer can be represent in difference of power sum?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,m,n$ are positive integers with, if $m= 1$ then $n\ne 1$ and vice versa.

Let define

$S_m(a)=1^m+2^m+...+a^m$

and $S_n(b)=1^n+2^n+...+b^n$

> **Question**
>
> > Show that every $k\in \mathbb{N}$ can be represented as
> >
> > $$ k = S_m(a)-S_n(b)$$

**Example**

$1=1^2+2^2-(1+2)$

$2= 1+2-(1^2)$

$3= 1^4+2^4-(1^2+2^2+3^2)$

$4= 1^2+2^2-(1^2)$

$5= 1^2+2^2+3^2-(1^3+2^3)$

$6= 1^3+2^3+3^3-(1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2)$

$7= 1^4+2^4-(1+2+3+4)$

$8= 1^4+2^4-(1^3+2^3)$

$9=1^2+2^2+3^2-(1^2+2^2)$

$10= 1+2+3+4+5-(1^2+2^2)$

$\vdots$

Comment: which differences can powers create ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee only condition  is if $m=1$ then $n\ne 1$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: $1+2+3+4+5+6-(1^2+2^2+3^2)=7$ is another one for 7.

Comment: @Pruthviraj How can $17$ be represented ?

Comment: $17=S_9(2)-S_1(31)$.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, most positive integers $k$ cannot be represented in this way, though proving such a result is, I believe, rather out of range of current technology. Perhaps $k=163$ is the first non-representable $k$, though I didn't try very hard to verify this (actually proving this for even one fixed $k$ is likely extremely hard).

Comment: Thank you for your time I'm trying  on 163. Maybe you like this [problem][1]. [1]:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364721/647719

Comment: So if change as $S_m(a)+qS_n(b)$ where $q\in \{-1,1\}$ and $a,b$ are non negative integer so $163=S_4(3)+S_2(6)$ then is it flexible to able to prove for $k=S_m(a)+qS_n(b)$

Comment: I got the representation for $163$ more difficult is $293$